bindkey ^[[A - How do I use it?
I once found this in one guy's .zshrc:
# matches current input to history items
# bind to up arrow and down arrow
bindkey '^[[A' history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey '^[[B' history-beginning-search-forward

How do I use it? On a Mac keyboard, I've tried Control-A, Option-A, Command-A, Escape-A, as well as pressing Escape, releasing it, and then pressing A. And nothing useful happens.

"as well as pressing Escape, releasing it, and then pressing A" – Escape, [ and then (capital) A should work, if typed fast enough. The intended usage is to press up though.

The comment says:

# bind to up arrow and down arrow

^[[A/^[[B] mean up/down arrow keys, you can try it yourself in Bash or Zsh
by pressing Control-v, releasing it and presing Up/Down arrow key.
You can read more here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Terminal_input_sequences
